# Cleaning up after shutdown request

Tags: ros, xmlrpc, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my node looping portion, I check for shutdown using `ros::isShuttingDown()`. After the looping portion, I wish to perform a couple of actions before shutdown. The reason for this is that I am attempting to programatically start and stop nodes. The node is being stopped either with `CTRL-C` or `rosnode kill`

However, this doesn't seem to function as I hope.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
 while(!ros::isShuttingDown()){
 //while(ros::ok()) { // Does not work either.

      ros::spinOnce();
      rate.sleep();
  }

  //EDIT:
  ROS_INFO("will not print");
  fflush(stdout);

  //FIXME Cleanup section not running
  // Cleanup

  localizer.nh.setParam(
    strcat(strcat(strcpy(localizer_node_param, "/"),
    LOCALIZER_NODE),"_running"), false);

  return SUCCESS;
```

In this instance, the parameter is not re-set at the end of life of this node. Can someone reproduce this  behavior? Simple loop and ROS_INFO() statement is sufficient.

EDIT: ROS log statements also do not print to stdout when placed as shown (with or without `fflush(stdout);`)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253661/cleaning-up-after-shutdown-request/) by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-03**:
I am not fully aware of how the shutdown is implemented. But it could be in the process of shutting down, the parameter cannot be written to the parameter server, due to the shutdown itself...

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-02-03**:
See edit. ROS log statements don't print out either. I get the sense that the code after the looping portion does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When ROS is shutting down, it drops all connections to the master and afaik thus looses all "ROS"-Functionality.
I.e. you cannot

- publish or subscribe to a topic
- call a service or action
- read to or write from the Parameter server
- and apparently all ROS logging does not work either.

If you replace the ROS_INFO with a `std::cout`, you see that this is actually handled. However, all code with ROS functionality is, in the end, a noop, due to the missing connections.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-02-07**:
This seems to be correct. Where is this documented?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-08**:
I don't know. There is http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown

> At any time you may call the ros::shutdown() function to shutdown your node. This will kill all open subscriptions, publications, service calls, and service servers.

But this does not explicitely talk ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-08**:
about Parameters. It is, however, talking about the use of `ros::isShuttingDown`.